# Expand a widget until it reaches the minHeight of it's parent

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to expand a container to fill the space until it reaches parent's `minHeight`. Right now it automatically expands to `maxHeight` and `minHeight` is ignored because of it.

My example is below. I want the grey bar that is right below the blue part to be at the bottom of the red part. If I put a `Spacer` or `Expanded` after the blue container it expands the whole modal bottom sheet to it's `maxSize`. I also tried using `Align` widget on the grey bar but it doesn't change it's position at all.

[image: example of the problem]

Code that produces the UI above:

```
Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: ScrPaddings.top8Padding,
                child: HorizontalBarIndicator(
                  width:
                      ScrPaddings(context).screenWidthRelativeTo390(32.0),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: ChatListView(
                  conversation: state.conversation,
                  showPendingAnimationBubble: true,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: ScrPaddings.bottom8Padding,
                child: HorizontalBarIndicator(
                  width:
                      ScrPaddings(context).screenWidthRelativeTo390(134.0),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the desired UI by separating the widgets that should be in the top and the widgets that should be in the bottom in two `Column` widgets that have `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` and adding this parameter to the parent `Column` - `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`.

This separated both child `Column` widgets without expanding the modal bottom sheet to it's `maxSize`. It only expanded to `minSize` and continued expanding after the children within started to increase in size.

The full code that achieved the desired look:

```
 Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: ScrPaddings(context).screenHeightRelativeTo844(8),
                ),
                HorizontalBarIndicator(
                  width:
                      ScrPaddings(context).screenWidthRelativeTo390(32.0),
                ),
                ChatListView(
                  conversation: state.conversation,
                  showPendingAnimationBubble: true,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                const CallInformationBar(
                  title: '+49 30 504489445',
                ),
                HorizontalBarIndicator(
                  width:
                      ScrPaddings(context).screenWidthRelativeTo390(134.0),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: ScrPaddings(context).screenHeightRelativeTo844(8),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The container widget automatically expands to take up as much space as possible if a height is not given manually or by its parent. Give the container the same height as the minHeight of the parent.

And if you want to change the height of the modal sheet you can do so with FractionallySizedBox like this:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    builder: (context) {
      return FractionallySizedBox(
        heightFactor: 0.4,
        child: Container(),
      );
    });
```

Setting isScrollControlled to true allows the user to make it bigger if need be.